# Why is a ActiveRecord query with a less than operator in a having clause not returning the expected records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This first squeel query gives me what I expect: all of the QuoteStops with the highest sequence for their given quote.

```
QuoteStop.joins{quote}.group{quote.id}.having{sequence == max(sequence)}.pluck("quote_stops.sequence")

SELECT quote_stops.sequence FROM "quote_stops" INNER JOIN "quotes" ON "quotes"."id" = "quote_stops"."quote_id" GROUP BY "quotes"."id" HAVING "quote_stops"."sequence" = max("quote_stops"."sequence")

[2, 3 ... 2]
```

But, if I change the comparison in the having clause to `<` the SQL looks right but the result is an empty list when I'd like to be all of the QuoteStops that didn't have the highest sequence.

```
QuoteStop.joins{quote}.group{quote.id}.having{ sequence < max(sequence) }.pluck("quote_stops.sequence")

SELECT quote_stops.sequence FROM "quote_stops" INNER JOIN "quotes" ON "quotes"."id" = "quote_stops"."quote_id" GROUP BY "quotes"."id" HAVING "quote_stops"."sequence" < max("quote_stops"."sequence")

[]
```

What am I missing? Squeel or ActiveRecord answers are fine.